# Printing Plots in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to print a plot in Matlab and print it as a pdf but I keep encountering an error. I appreciate your help and input.

```
x = [2 4 7 2 4 5 2 5 1 4];
plot(x);
fig=gcf;
print(1,'-dpdf')

Warning: Files produced by the 'pdfwrite'
driver cannot be sent to printer.
File saved to disk under name 'figure1.pdf'. 
> In name (line 73)
  In print (line 200) 
Error using name (line 102)
Cannot create output file '.\figure1.pdf'.

Error in print (line 200)
    pj = name( pj );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have write permissions for wherever the print function is trying to put the file. Try using an absolute path.

Example on Linux:

```
print('~/figure1.pdf', '-dpdf');
```

Or Windows

```
print('C:\MyFolder\figure1.pdf', '-dpdf');
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked. Do you by any chance know how to have two different graphs, each in a different Matlab GUI?

Comment: In other words, multiple GUI's. Every time I plot something, the graph in the GUI is erased and the same GUI is used to make another plot.

Comment: If you use the command `figure(x)` where x is some integer it will change focus to that figure or create figure x if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Do you know how to plot two different graphs, each in its own GUI? Both displayed at the same time? Every time I plot, the prior graph in the GUI gets deleted.

Comment: I think the comment above does exactly that. If you run the command `figure(1); plot(rand(10,1)); figure(2); plot(rand(10,1));` then you will plot two different figure windows. The first in Figure 1 and the second in Figure 2. They may be placed in the same location on the screen so you will probably need to drag Figure 2 off of Figure 1.